# How do I ng-init a variable with nothing?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-init

This line currently triggers an error because probably there is nothing after the second =.
What value should return from php to tell filterSubject that is empty.

ng-init="filterSubject="

In some cases filterSubject= gets populated with an id from the query string like ?subject=11
but what do I have to pass from php when the query string is not present

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it looks like you're generating the string in PHP, put single quotes around the filter subject:

```
ng-init="filterSubject='$subject'"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ternary operator something like this

```
ng-init="filterSubject = YOUR_EXPRESSION || ''"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :-

```
<div <?php if($_GET['subject']){ ?>ng-init="filterSubject='<?php echo $_GET['subject']; ?>'" <?php }?>>
.....
</div>
```

or

```
<?php
if($_GET['subject']){
$nginit = 'ng-init="filterSubject=\''.$_GET['subject'].'\'"';
}
?>

<div <?php echo $nginit;?>>
.....
</div>
```

Comment: this one should work as well but I wanted to not generate ng attributes from php